# Applying Blending Options to group doesn’t work as expected

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, layer-style

When applying my Gradient Overlay to a group of layers, the gradient doesn’t size to fit the minimum frame of the layers in that group. So for example, a green to red gradient shows up on the group as just a block green colour. However, when I apply the same blending options to each layer individually, the gradient works as expected.

Group Blending Options:

[image]

Individual layers:

[image]

The group contains just a text layer and a smart object. I’ve checked the smart object (it’s from Illustrator) and the art board is sized to fit the contents.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Would you care to explain how did you apply the "group blending option"?

Comment: I added the Gradient Overlay on top of the group.

Comment: If there is no group, just two layers and you put the gradient on top of both, does it achieve the result you want? If so, why do you need to put the cut off circle and Ps in a group, what is the reason? To get a better idea, also provide the blend mode of each layer as well as the blend mode of the group, and the blend mode of the gradient layer.

Comment: All blend modes are normal. It does work well, but there are a ton of these circles so they’re grouped to make the layers cleaner. Well, of course the result can be achieved through separate layers but creating two of the same blending options creates erroneous data (doubling up data). Also, this seems like a problem that should be reported as a bug if there is no solution so I was checking if I need to report it or not.

Comment: Why don't you change the group blend mode to "Pass Through" not normal? Let's see what happens.